# Deep learning model stuck in local minima or overfit?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I trained an image classification model of 10 classes by finetuning EfficientNet-B4 for 100 epochs. I split my training data to 70/30. I used stochastic gradient descent with Nesterov momentum of 0.9 and the starting learning rate is 0.001. The batch size is 10. The test loss seemed to stuck at 84% for the next 50 epochs (51st - 100th). I do not know whether the model was stuck in local minima or the model was overfitted. Below is an image of the test and train loss from 51st epoch to 100th. I need your help a lot. Thanks. [Train test loss image from 51st to 100th epoch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuGnN.png)

Comment: I meant test accuracy stuck at 84%

Comment: can you upload the model summary as well ?

Comment: Sure! Below is the link to txt doc containing the model summary. https://drive.google.com/open?id=18wlMr8aPHW3T4lctcBVnOFtms86kQcS_

Answer (score 0):

From the graph you provided, both validation and training losses are still going down so your model is still training and there is no overfit. If your test set is stuck at the same accuracy, the reason is probably that the data you are using for your training/validation dataset does not generalize well enough on your test dataset (in your graph the validation only reached 50% accuracy while your test set reached 84% accuracy).

Comment: Does it mean that I have to improve my data? Instead of improving the data, what are the other options that I have?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your training and validation graph. yes, your model is training and the losses are going down, but your validation error is near 50%, which means 'random guess'.

Possible reasons-

1- From your train error (which is presented in the image between 50-100 epoch), the error in average is going down, but it's random. like your error at epoch 100 is pretty much the same at epoch 70. This could be because your either dataset is too simple and you are forcing huge network like an efficient net to overfit it.

2- it could also be because of the way you are finetuning it, there could be any problem. like which all layers you froze and for which layer you are taking the gradients while doing BP. I am assuming you are using pre-trained weights.

3- Optimizer issue. try to use Adam

It would be great if you can provide total losses (from epoch 1 - 100).

Comment: As you suggest, I have to use a smaller network. I have retrained it with EfficientNet-B0 compared to the previous network which is EfficientNet-B4. Yes, I used pre-trained weights and froze all other layers and only train the classifier (_fc ). The network architecture that I used. (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vNISAjJWP9QmvHEHfClcoV4teRGMBRDJ). I trained the model for 400 epochs and here's the loss. (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Bc4RiwH7m0g9LLmTA2FrZze-1Z_mw7D7). The model still doesn't perform well. I used the exact same optimizer. What's the difference when I use Adam?